# Non integer index of summation

Tags: math-mode, equations, symbols

I have following equation:

[image]

I would like to use summation for the above equation. The index of summation is not an integer. Can I use the below equation to represent the above equation?

[image]

Comment: That is not really a LaTeX question, but rather about math notation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off-topic for [tex.se].

Answer (score 2):

As daleif said, not really a LaTeX question. But while we're here, my opinion:

The names `a1.1`, `a1.2` etc are really unconvential for mathematical objects. Instead, consider putting the number in subscript, like `$ a_{1.2} $`. However, if they are mathematical objects, I would consider this perfectly fine notation.

Do note however you don't want too long of a subscript under your summation! For instance, here I would put `$ I = \{a_{1.1}, a_{1.2}, a_{2}\} $` and then use `$ \sum_{i\in I} $` in the equation.

Comment: You could even write `$\sum_i$`, and then say "where the sum ranges over ...".